# Creating a custom data extension with Exact target

Tags: exacttarget

My company started using exact target a little while ago. 
We are using shared data extensions and a unique data extension per email. 
We use a template to create all of our data extensions - TriggeredSendDataExtension.

The problem is this template only has two fields - SubscriberKey and EmailAddress.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a custom Data extension template so i won't have 
to enter the reoccurring data again every time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found a workaround to help me create a more hierarchical system. I created a generic data extension using the TriggeredSendDataExtension. After i created the generic data extension i created the rest of my DE's as a copy of an existing DE. That way i did not have to reenter all of my fields again and again. It is a workaround but it works!

Comment: if you found an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer and mark it as so.  That way future people with the same problem won't have to figure it out on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Data Extension templates are only available to the backend of ExactTarget. The method you described above (copying existing) is the recommended route.